# Bulk API 2.0 works in sandbox but broken in production

Tags: rest-api, api, bulk-api

I'm trying to bulk import Task records using the Bulk API 2.0, which works perfectly fine in the sandbox, but fails with this error every time when I try to create the job in production:

`[{"errorCode":"INVALIDJOB","message":"InvalidJob : Unable to find object: Task"}]`

Then I tried following the documentation example exactly by using `Contact` as the `object`, but I just get the same error:

`[{"errorCode":"INVALIDJOB","message":"InvalidJob : Unable to find object: Contact"}]`

I double checked that the app has full access to the API, so it doesn't seem to be a permissions issue.

Comment: can you provide a body of call.

Comment: The app might have full access to the api... but does the user have access to the objects?

Comment: @SebastianKessel That's a great question, I'm new to Salesforce and am not entirely familiar with the permissions system. I'll check tomorrow.

Comment: @SebastianKessel Tested with a different Salesforce account and it works perfectly. Looks like you were correct that it was a permissions issue. Would you like to repost your comment as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ben, this sounds as if the user in question does not have access to the objects. I recommend you either adjust the user's profile or try with a new user.